# Is my indentation the cause of yaml 21: did not find expected key?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

when running docker-compose up -d
I received one of many YAML: line 21: did not find expected key- below is the code:

```
services:
    flask-app:
      build: ./flask-app
      ports:
      - target: 5000
        published: 5000
        protocol: tcp
    database:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: mysql
    ports:
    - target: 3306
      published: 3306
      enviroment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password123
        MYSQL_DATABSE: flask-db
    volumes:
    - type: volumne
    source: mysql
    target: /var/lib/mysql
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
    - target: 80
    published: 80
    protocol: tcp
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ./nginx/nginx.conf
      target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

volumes:
MySQL:
```

I have been playing around with this for ages and it's just driving me mad- so would appreciate a different set of eyes on this in case I have missed anything.

Comment: How is this related to Python or programming in general?

Comment: As you've quoted this in the question, you lose a step of indentation on the `database: { ports: }`, and at the end, `MySQL:` needs to be indented under `volumes:`.  In particular, under `services:`, you have some things indented by at least 4 spaces, and then on line 21 (`nginx:`) it's suddenly indented by only 2 spaces, and that's the reported YAML parse error.

Answer (score 1):

The line `nginx:` is indented two spaces. It occurs after an outer mapping has been started with `services:` at zero spaces, and an inner mapping has been started with `flask-app:` which is indented four spaces. `nginx:` has the wrong indentation for each of those mappings, this is why you get an error.

Your other indentations are very weird too. Does `ports:` not belong inside `database:`? Does `source: mysql` not belong inside `volumes:`? Does `published: 80` not belong inside `ports:`?

I suggest reviewing the indentations in the whole file and ensuring that each line is at the correct level and has the correct parent.